# Pandas - DF with lists - find all rows that match a string in any of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID     col1        col2     col3
0     ['a','b'] ['d','c'] ['e','d']
1     ['s','f'] ['f','a'] ['d','aaa']
```

Give an `input string = 'a'`
I want to receive a dataframe like this:

```
ID     col1      col2     col3
0       1          0        0
1       0          1        0
```

I see how to do it with a `for` loop but that takes forever, and there must be a method I miss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing lists in pandas is not vectorized supported, so performance is worse like scalars.

First idea is reshape lists columns to `Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create scalars by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), so possible compare by `a`, test if match per first levels by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html), and last reshape back with convert boolean mask to integers:

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID').stack().explode().eq('a').any(level=[0,1]).unstack().astype(int)
print (df1)
    col1  col2  col3
ID                  
0      1     0     0
1      0     1     0
```

Or is possible use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise testing by lambda function with `in`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID').applymap(lambda x: 'a' in x).astype(int)
```

Or create for each lists column `DataFrame`, so possible test by `a` with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index).eq('a').any(axis=1)
df1 = df.set_index('ID').apply(f).astype(int)
```